# Laravel Seeder - Sequence Index Bug

Tags: php, laravel, factory, laravel-factory

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a misunderstanding on my part...

Reading the documentation on [sequences](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#sequences) and [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#has-many-relationships) i'd have expected the below code to reset the `$sequence->index` within the report factory after each user was created, however it persists for all users.

The intended effect should be each user has 90 days of reports from now, however the increment keeps growing meaning in the end the last user reports end 900 days ago (not 90).

```php
    \App\Models\Recipient::factory(10)
            ->sequence(fn ($sequence) => [
                'player_id' => $playerIds[$sequence->index]
            ])
            ->has(
                \App\Models\Report::factory(90)
                    ->sequence(fn ($sequence) => [
                        'created_at' => now()->subDay($sequence->index)
                    ])
                    ->state(fn (array $attributes, \App\Models\Recipient $recipient) => [
                        'player_id' => $recipient->player_id,
                        'user_id' => $recipient->user_id
                    ])
            )
            ->create([
                'user_id' => 34
            ]);
```

I believe this is a bug in the library itself, most likely due to some static value, or have I misunderstood the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

In case you're still having this issue, this is how I was able to use the $index variable:

```
`\App\Models\Recipient::factory(10)
    ->state(new Sequence (fn ($sequence) => ['id' => $sequence->index]))
    ->create();`
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry no one has answered you yet. This problem is simple. Try it:

```php
\App\Models\Recipient::factory(10)
            ->sequence(fn ($sequence) => [
                'player_id' => $playerIds[$sequence->index%10]
            ])
            ->has(
                \App\Models\Report::factory(90)
                    ->sequence(fn ($sequence) => [
                        'created_at' => now()->subDay($sequence->index%90)
                    ])
                    ->state(fn (array $attributes, \App\Models\Recipient $recipient) => [
                        'player_id' => $recipient->player_id,
                        'user_id' => $recipient->user_id
                    ])
            )
            ->create([
                'user_id' => 34
            ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however the question is more about this being a bug in Laravel factory rather than looking how to bypass this bug. Appreciate your input though!